# Best Practice - ASP.NET/Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, identity

My question evolves around best practice.

Right now im using entity framework with ASP.NET and would like it top performance.

Would you generally check in the database for a existing record before adding one, or would you rely on the exception being throw or even expect that the parameters given are relevant and active.

Example: (ASP.NET with Identity)

```
public ResultWrapper AddUserToRole(string user, bool userId, string role, bool roleId)
{
    ApplicationUser appUser = FindUser(user, userId);
    ApplicationRole appRole = FindRole(role, roleId);

    if (appUser == null || appRole == null)
        return new ResultWrapper(false, "Unknown user or role");
    else
    {
        IdentityResult result = userManager.AddToRole(appUser.Id, appRole.Name);
        db.SaveChanges(); // AutoSaveChanges is false, so update.
        return new ResultWrapper(result.Succeeded, result.Errors);
    }
}
```

Comment: This question might be better suited to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm not sure why you're worried about top performance adding a user to a role...  it's not a giant blocking operation.

Comment: If you would like top performance then don't rely on throwing exceptions... ever. Exceptions are classed as 'expensive' in terms of performance and should not be used in normal logic/program flow. If you're adding a new user do the check first. If i was you i would create your application then sort out any performance issues. (But always keep performance in mind, this is something that you get better at the more you program)

Comment: Exception are designed for abnormal scenarios, not for your business logic. You should implement a DB check and insert after you're certain that it will not throw an exception. When the exception happens, you know that something really broke down. That's why they exist. IMHO, you should NEVER rely on exception. They are what their name say: an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides being a very opinion based question, I think there are appropriate guidelines one can follow.

> Would you generally check in the database for a existing record before adding one, or would you rely on the exception being throw or even expect that the parameters given are relevant and active.

This completely depends on context in my opinion.

For extremely high transactions, I would write a stored procedure.

Otherwise it depends on the concurrency of the operation, and in this particular instance, I don't think multiple people are going to try to add the same person to the same role, so exceptions are minimized and acceptable.